# command prompt here doesn't work in a directory/folder under the control of clearcase

Tags: windows, command, clearcase

This is really just an annoyance, but I'd like to see if someone has solved it.

I really love and need to have the Windows power toy "command prompt here".
I installed it first day on the XP laptop my new client gave me.
It works well in All folders EXCEPT those under the control of Base Clear Case.

If I create a junction (symbolic link) to that folder, and navigate to that, it does show in the pop-up menu.

I am thinking the clear case registry entry is overriding the command prompt here, 
but I don't need this enough to muck about in registry on my clients machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative method that seems to work using file associations.

These are set under Tools / Folder Options / File Types in windows Explorer.

Reference Method #3 in the following link:

http://www.petri.co.il/add_command_prompt_here_shortcut_to_windows_explorer.htm

Now on to find the next annoyance.

Comment: That didn't work for long, don't know what else happened to break it (some auto update or something else I installed).  I found the Command Prompt toolbar, which does what I need to regardless of what's in the pop-up menu.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it working on snapshot views (which are really simple files/directories on the `C:` drive), but not on dynamic views (which are mounted directory on the device `M:`)

The ClearCase submenu shouldn't matter, except it [doesn't show up on Windows64](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21251833).
From [technote swg1PK36107](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg1PK36107):

> ClearCase is a 32-bit application, therefore, the ClearCase and Windows Explorer integration will only work in a 32-bit Windows Explorer.

Maybe that limitation might have a side-effect for your own "command prompt here" plugin?

Comment: Thanks, The Command-Prompt-Here hack is one of the windows PowerToys, and not one of the many registry hacks found elsewhere on the net. It is a static view.  Guess I'll need to dig into what part(s) of the registry the explorer uses for the context menus to figure this one out.

Comment: @Rawheiser: by static view, I suppose you mean a snapshot view (with its root on `C:\path\to\snapshot\view`)? Let us know if you find anything.